# Prove: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|*_{i=1}^nf(x)\|_2=0$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The following is a part of a question which I have answered

Let $
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, \mid x \mid<\frac{1}{2} \\
0, \mid x \mid\geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$

1. Find Fourier transform:

   For $\omega=0: \hat{f}(0)=\frac{1}{4\pi}$

   For $\omega\neq 0:\hat{f}(\omega) =\frac{\sin(\frac{\omega}{2})}{\omega}$
2. Find the Fourier transform of the convolution
   $f_n(x) = *_{i=1}^{n}f(x)=f(x)*f(x)*\cdots*f(x)$

   For $\omega=0: \hat{f_n}(0)=\frac{2\pi }{(4\pi)^n}$

   For $\omega\neq 0:\hat{f_n}(\omega) = \frac{\sin^n(\frac{\omega}{2})}{\omega^n}$

Now I am asked to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|*_{i=1}^nf(x)\|_2=0$, I know that $\lim_{\omega\to \infty}F(\omega)=0$ how should I approach this?

Comment: You know that the Fourier transform is a map from $L^2$ to $L^2$.  How does the Fourier transform act in relation to the $L^2$-norm?

Comment: @GregK Plancherel theorem? $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(\omega)|^2 d \omega$

Comment: Yes!  So if you need to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lVert *_{i=1}^n f \rVert_2$, it suffices to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lVert \frac{sin^n(\omega/2)}{\omega^n} \rVert_2$, which you should be able to do with the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @GregK we are not looking at $\frac{2\pi}{(4\pi)^n}$ as it is obvious  that the limit is zero? as for dominated convergence theorem I just know that from lebesgue that when taking the limit of  the coefficients of the Fourier series we get $0$

Comment: When computing the $L^2$ norm, the value of the transform at $\omega = 0$ is not relevant (since we are computing an integral and $\{0\}$ has measure 0), so we don't need to worry about the $\frac{2\pi}{(4\pi)^n}$.  As far as your second comment goes, we aren't so worried about the limit of the coefficients, as we are worried about the limit of the $L^2$ norm.  You need to dominate the functions $\left(\frac{\sin^n(\omega/2)}{\omega^n}\right)^2$ by an $L^1$ function in order to move the limit inside the integral.

Comment: I can write up a few more of the details in an answer if that would be helpful.

Comment: @GregK I did not learn about measure, it is a into course in Fourier, maybe I just need to know that I can move the limit in $L^2$?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'm not sure how this should go without the dominated convergence theorem.  But yes, it is a fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lVert \frac{\sin^n(\omega/2)}{\omega^n}\rVert_2 = \lVert \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin^n(\omega/2)}{\omega^n} \rVert_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer won't be the most helpful to the OP (apologies), but it may be helpful for others, so I'll post it anyways.

Let $f_n(x) = *_{i=1}^n f(x)$.  The Fourier transform is an isometry from $L^2$ to $L^2$.  Hence, if we want to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|f_n\|_2$, it suffices to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|\hat{f_n}\|_2$.

Since $\hat{f_n}(\omega) = \frac{\sin^n(\omega/2)}{\omega^n}$, we want to compute $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|\hat{f_n}\|_2^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2 \,d\omega$$

The goal, then, is to bound $|\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2$ by some $g(\omega) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Since we have for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$, we note that $|\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2 \leq \left|\frac{(\omega/2)^{2n}}{\omega^{2n}}\right| \leq 1$.

Now, we also have the bound $|\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2 \leq \frac{1}{\omega^{2n}} \leq \frac{1}{\omega^2}$.

Applying both of these bounds, we see that if we let $$g(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1 & \omega \in [-1,1] \\ \frac{1}{\omega^2} & \omega \notin [-1,1]\end{cases}$$ then $g \in L^1$ and $|\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2 \leq g(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then, apply the dominated convergence theorem to find that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|f_n\|_2^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|\hat{f_n}\|_2^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2 \,d\omega = \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\hat{f_n}(\omega)|^2 \,d\omega = 0$$